# SQL Server - Columns without a value 'H'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My SQLServer table 'Users' is like

```
User               Usertype
---------------------------
Mike                     S
Sally                    S
Alan                     S
Sally                    H
Alan                     S  
Mike                     S
Mike                     H
```

I am trying to build a query on this table which should return the user that has no 'H' usertype. For e.g., the above table should return 'Alan' as this user has no 'H' pair, while Mike and Sally has at least one 'H'.

Kindly help

Comment: You could also use EXCEPT ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group by the user and then check how many `H` types each user has. That number must be `0` for the ones you are looking for.

```
select [user]
from your_table
group by [user]
having sum(case when usertype = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It return the result 'Alas'.

> select distinct User from Users where User not IN(
>   select a.User from Users a join  Users b
>   on a.User=b.User and a.Usertype!=b.Usertype)

Demo **SQL FIDDLE**:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f175/24